# How to load the windows partion in ubuntu at startup itself by default

Tags: partitioning, startup-applications

sudo mkdir /media/D

sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sda4 /media/D

I did this but it is not loading at startup itself.

How to load the windows partition in the startup?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this? I mean by startup if you mean before logging into ubuntu, for what do you need the windows partition?

Answer (score 1):

The `mount` command is only used to mount a file system until the system reboots (or until you manually unmount it).

If you want to mount a file system automatically on every boot, you will have to add the following line to the file `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda4 /media/D ntfs nls=utf8,umask=0222 0 2
```

More information can be found in `man fstab`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using the gnome disk manager tool. When you select the partition you want to unlock at startup there you're able to change the mount options to custom mount options. Then you can just check the Box that it should mount on startup.